# reusing previously generated random samples

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, sample-size, simulation

Suppose, I wish to generate random samples from normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I already have a `normrand()` function.

***Technique 1*** Each time a random sample is needed, I generate a new one using `normrand()`function.

***Technique 2*** Initially, I generate large number of (say $N\geq 10,000$) normally distributed random samples using `normrand()` and store them in a vector *norm_sample*. Now, whenever I need a sample from the normal distribution, I just pick a uniformly distributed random number $k$ between 1 and $N$ return *norm_sample[k]*.

My questions are:

1. Is ***Technique 1*** equivalent to ***Technique 2***? Why or why not?
2. If it is valid, Can I use ***Technique 2*** to generate more than $N$ random samples? As in what is the maximum number of samples I can generate using ***Technique 2***?

Comment: It's not clear why you would ever want to do this.  Why not just use normrand() every time?

Comment: **There are huge problems with Technique 2:** it can give bad results in some applications without providing any indication that it has utterly failed. For instance, it's more likely than not that all your 10000 samples will lie between -4 and 4. In, say, a lengthy simulation in which you are estimating the rate of a rare event that would occur only when a random value is greater than 4, *you would never see that event no matter how long you ran the simulation.* This problem is not confined to rare events. For instance, the mean of a long simulation will never converge to $\mu$!

Comment: @StatsStudent: Technique 2 can prove to be cheaper in some situations.

Comment: @whuber: That's a very good point. Can you put it as an answer so that It can be accepted?

Comment: @Chatter, what is your definition of "cheaper?"  It's not cheaper since you'd get bad results with the technique 2.  They aren't equivalent.

Comment: @StatsStudent yes, now I know that its not correct :). However, I thought that _if_ technique 2 was valid for all k >= N, _then_ it would be cheaper than technique 1. Unfortunately, that's not the case.